# how do you through loop a certain date range

Tags: shell, date, sed, awk, range

I have files  in a directory that are date based  but not obviously date-stamped.

```
File_yyyymmdd_record.log
```

These are lying around in a directory for  a few years worth of time.
Now if these were simply numbers all I needed to do was get the difference and incremenet a counter to push the value

```
var=substring( File_yyyymmdd_record.log ) /* get the yyyymmdd part */
var2=substring( File2_yyyymmdd_record.log ) /* get the yyyymmdd part */
delta=var2-var1
set i=delta and loop through to get the values for all these recordID's ( record ID    is the yyyymmdd part )
```

The problem is if I have 2  different months and also years  in the directory say 20131210 and 20140110 
the difference not going to gimme all the recordID's in that directory , since, when it spills over to the next month the plain numeric calculation is not applicable- it should be a date based calculation.
what I want to do is use 2 input parameters to the shell

```
 shell.sh recordID1 recordID2
```

and based on these it will find  all records  and store them some place and loop through each record as an input like this

```
find <dir> -iname recordID* ...<some awk and sed here> |
   while read recordID ;
   do <stuff >
   done
```

Anyway this can be achieved esp in 2 contexts-
First the date calculation part and the other is to store these recordID's so I can cycle through them. Maybe echo them to a tmp file is what comes off the bat.

For the date calculation part - I tried this and it works . But not sure if it will falter some time / situation

```
echo $((($(date -u -d 2010-04-29 +%s) - $(date -u -d 2010-03-28 +%s)) / 86400))
```

So given recordID1 as 20100328 I have 32 days  recordID's to look for in that directory.
You have to advance dates for 32 days from recordID1 and store them some place.
How best can all this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your points, you need find out log files with file name between 20131210 and 20140110 .
**(no need convert to epoch time)**

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

sep=20131210 
eep=20140110 

find /DIR -type f -name "*.log" |while read file
do
  d=${file:5:8}
  if [ "$d" -ge "$sep" ] && [ "$d" -le "$eep" ]; then
     do <stuff >
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do:

```
s=20130102 # start date
e=20130202 # end date

sep=$(date +"%s" -d"$s") # conv to epoch
eep=$(date +"%s" -d"$e")
for f in *.log; do
    d=$(date +"%s" -d$(sed -n 's/^[^_]*_\([^_]*\)_[^_]*.log/\1/p' <<< "$f"))
    if [ "$d" -ge "$sep" ] && [ "$d" -le "$eep" ]; then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

Comment: e.g.here is an e.g. of directory and contents `/testdir contents : datalog.20131030.part.001 datalog20131030.part.002 datalog20120910.part.001 datalog20120910.part.002 datalog20130930.part.001 datalog20130930.part.002 ` `shell.ksh 20130930 201310301` should pick up each part.001 and part002 file   for 20130930 &  201310301 series. Isolate the recordID - the yyyymmdd of these and file names. For this directory- give me all files that match that range and their record id ( echo those names ) TY again